# Delphi code to turn on screen saver doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-screensaver, wm-syscommand

I have a Delphi app that places the computer into screensave using

```
hWnd := GetDesktopWindow ;
SendMessage (hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0) ;
```

This works fine under XP but I find it doesn't work under (embedded) Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ahaa.  Problem was there was no (Windows) screen saver set up on the embedded machine.  I was fooled by the fact that the screen in fact did turn off after a delay, but that appears to be a hardware behaviour of the tablet PC.  Both SendMessage (<desktop handle>, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0) ; and SendMessage (<main windows handle>, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0) ; seem to return a value of zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me (Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit). Have you tried to send the message to another window, such as `Handle`? (Also, are you sure that you *have* a screensaver installed?)

Answer (score 0):

The SC_SCREENSAVE message tells the target window to execute the screen saver application specified in the [boot] section of the System.ini file. As the o/s is Embedded windows, which is a cut-down version of windows, quiet likely the system.ini file is configured for no screen-saver. Check your system.ini file.

Comment: I don't think so. `system.ini` is only used as a compatibility relic for 16-bit applications. `system.ini` hasn't been used for real in Windows for quite some time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSTEM.INI